# Xamarin.Forms] What libraries can replace Xlabs?

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, xlabs

Xlabs no longer maintains Xamarin.Forms.
I need to replace the existing xlabs library I was using.
What can I use?
Do you have a library you can recommend?
Thank you :)

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic], section on off-topic questions, point 4: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"*

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm not able to comment on this.

It depends which controls of XLabs you need. Can you give some examples that we are able to check if there are something similar available.

Maybe you can take a look at the controls of [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin) which are free with the [community licence](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

If you can't use Syncfusion for example the easiest way is to create your own controls depending on the XLabs Controls. So you can copy the code an extend the functionality.

Comment: Hello Sebastian :)  need controls  CheckBox, RadioButton, ExtendedLabel .

Comment: But, I belong to a company and can not use community licenses.

Comment: In this case the easiest Way is to take the code of the XLabs controls and create your own controls depending on XLabs.

Answer (score 0):

I would build your own custom controls for CheckBox, RadioButton and ExtendedLabel based on the code from XLabs.

That way you'll be able to fix end extend it.